# Adding an additional parameter to a powershell command changes output from a delimited matrix to a long list

Tags: powershell, output

Why when i run:

```
Get-Service | select-object  Status, Name, DisplayName, @{Name="ComputerName";Expression={$env:COMPUTERNAME}}
```

do i get a delimited matrix output like:

> ```
> Status Name               DisplayName                            ComputerName                                  
> ------ ----               -----------                            ------------                                  
> Running AeLookupSvc       Application Experience                 PROD01                                       
> Stopped ALG               Application Layer Gateway Service      PROD01                                       
> Stopped AppIDSvc          Application Identity                   PROD01
> ```

But when i run

```
Get-Service | select-object  Status, Name, DisplayName, @{Name="ComputerName";Expression={$env:COMPUTERNAME}}, @{Name="RunDate";Expression={get-date -f "yyyymmdd HHmm"}}
```

I get a running list like:

> ```
> Status       : Running
> Name         : AeLookupSvc
> DisplayName  : Application Experience
> ComputerName : PROD01   
> RunDate      : 20183210 1632
>
> Status       : Stopped
> Name         : ALG
> DisplayName  : Application Layer Gateway Service
> ComputerName : PROD01   
> RunDate      : 20183210 1632
>
> Status       : Stopped
> Name         : AppIDSvc
> DisplayName  : Application Identity
> ComputerName : PROD01   
> RunDate      : 20183210 1632
> ```

Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perfectly normal.

The thing to understand about PowerShell vs. other shells is that generally commands return complete objects.

If those objects are sent out to screen, then they are *rendered* (*formatted* in PowerShell terms) according to a bunch of rules. Some types have their own special formatting rules built in (only show certain properties by default, display a certain way, etc.).

If there are no custom rules PowerShell determines whether to display it as a table or a list depending on some factors like how many properties are going to be displayed.

The important thing to remember is that is there is no real difference in what is being *returned* by the command, just how it is displayed.

You can control the display using `Format-*` commands, so you can do

```
Get-Process | Format-Table
Get-Process | Format-List
```

You can also control some aspects of how they are displayed (show properties normally hidden, show only some):

```
gps | Format-Table *  # not recommended
gps | ft Name,Id
```

This is similar to what you're doing with `Select-Object` on the surface, but there's a big difference: when you use a `Format-` command you *have lost the original object* so you should only use these for display purposes; typically in the shell.

`Select-Object` appears to do something similar but what it actually does is create a new generic object (`[PSObject]`) with only the properties you selected.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Should have tried those commands myself since I familiar with them.  I just didn't expect two different outputs with that change in the command.  I've used Linux (bash and python) previously and am just starting to use powershell (more and more).